# Public Chat Program: Windows Forms, C#

Tags: c#, winforms, networking, tcp

I'm new to Windows Forms, and the coding language I have learnt is C#.

I have searched the web far and wide to find a solution for my question, but all the solutions out there are for a local LAN network, and I need my program to communicate over my network and somebody else's network. I would like to be able to send a message to a friend through this program, and for them to be able to see it and respond back.

I'd like it if I could do this through IP addresses, as I've got a nice looking UI I have designed which contains a text box for my IP and port and the target IP and port.

Any solutions are appreciated, sorry if this is too vague or an obvious question.

*I'm using Visual Studio Community 2019 for coding inside, and am using Microsoft .NET Framework to create my programs. My PC runs Windows 10 Home 20H2.*

I was requested to include the tutorial I have followed, and it is this one: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/97ec13/how-to-make-a-chat-application-in-C-Sharp/

Comment: Why do you think that solutions which work on a local LAN network won't work on the wider internet? You'll probably need to set up port forwarding etc, but there's not much fundamentally different between a LAN and the internet

Comment: @canton7 only the amount of routers filtering traffic out there, but you already addressed the port forwarding ;-)

Comment: @canton7 Wow! Wasn't expecting such a quick response! I'm pretty new to this so anything is appreciated, if you have any ideas I'll take a look and see if they work.

Comment: @imrolii The first step is to answer my question, please

Comment: @canton7 The reason I believe that might not work is because all of the tutorials on google return a private IP address, and I'm not sure how to get them to return a public one and the software to be able to read a public one.

I'm a total noob at this, I signed up for StackOverflow just for this, sorry if I don't answer questions correctly/at all.

Comment: @imrolii It's important to illustrate in a question what you've tried so far that hasn't worked, so the folks here can give you guidance on what you might've missed. If you've tried some different tutorials, link them so we can see where you're getting hung up.

Comment: @imrolii Regarding how to acquire your peer's public IP: Unless they are behind some kind of data center, their IP is bound to change. So you'll have to have them register some kind of dynamic dns (DDNS) or have them return you the public IP every time it changes. They only have to google "My public IP" and it'll return them that. That still doesn't cover firewall, routers, port redirecting (and more) issues, though.

Comment: There are many ways to set up this architecture; Only one of which is actually having your peer sending something directly to your machine (and having to go through all the hassle previously mentioned). You can set up a public server, and have both your and their ends connected to it, as a web service, for instance.

Comment: @EricWu That's going to become an issue because I'm not gonna be able to set up things on other people's router's by any means... especially because the recipient(s) aren't the most technological...

Comment: @imrolii probably better to have a re-think and re-write the whole thing as a web application. If it's just for chat, a desktop app is probably a bit overkill anyway. More detail in my answer below, about how the networking works, and I mention the alternative web-based approach, which is how most people would design such an application these days anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem isn't about C# or WinForms, it's about networking and how TCP/IP networks operate. You won't be able to (easily) connect directly to your friend's computer because his computer is on another private network.

If it's a home computer, that network likely has a router which connects it to the internet. That router presents a single public IP address to the outside world, which is shared by all the computers within it, for the purpose of internet communication . It probably uses [Network Address Translation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) to translate between each individual device's local IP (see below) and the public IP when forwarding data. It also probably implements a firewall which prevents incoming connections.

For internal communication each machine, and the router, will have local IP addresses which are unique within that network, but are almost certainly not unique across the entire internet - but since these addresses are not visible outside the private network, that doesn't matter.

So, even if you try to send a message to the public IP address, which is reachable from anywhere, by default the router won't send the information on to a specific machine within that network. Firstly, the firewall prevents it (to stop malicious traffic entering the network), and secondly it doesn't know which specific device the message is intended for anyway.

Most routers offer a feature called [Port Forwarding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding) where you can configure it to accept incoming messages on a specific TCP port and forward them on to a specific device on the network. This would help you in your situation, but note that it can create a security vulnerability in your network and should be used with caution, only when you know what you're doing.

(If you're wondering, big company networks operate in a broadly similar way, with public and private IP addresses, but the actual implementation and features are more complex...the broad outcome is the same in terms of individual machines being inaccessible from outside the network. You don't, at this stage, need to worry about the other details.)

Note that the public IP of a private, domestic network can often change - Internet Service Providers don't usually provide a static IP for that type of network. So every time you want to connect, you will need to check with your friend what their current public IP address is. Or they can use a dynamic DNS service, so you can look it up based on a hostname.

---

P.S. Another alternative for you here is to re-write your chat application as a web application which can be hosted on a single, central public server and be accessed by anyone from anywhere, anytime. (You can of course use authentication to then restrict usage to those you wish to allow onto it.) These kinds of situations is one big reason why web applications have become so popular in the last 20 years.

A middle-ground approach would be to have a central server running somewhere (again needs to be publicly accessible - either on a cloud server or on a server in your network where you've set port-forwarding on your own router to expose it). In that scenario, all instances of the WinForms application would connect to that server, which would act as a hub for relaying messages. This is a pretty classic client-server architecture. You could even then have other clients (web app, mobile apps etc.) which can connect to the same server to take part in chat.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look on the Web for a tutorial on doing it though a Web app

Comment: No problem. Actually I would suggest this one: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio . Also, it's worth noting that if you set up such a SignalR server, you can also use SignalR to communicate with your existing WinForms application. And if you use (the free tier of) Azure SignalR you could maybe even convert your existing WinForms application to communicate via that SignalR hub without needing an asp.net application at all - you could potentially use serverless functions instead...

Comment: ... see - see https://www.serverless360.com/blog/azure-signalr-service-and-functions-to-build-real-time-serverless-application for information. Welcome to the 2020s.